# How to Wrap File and Pipe to New File in Same Directory in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to create a build system in Gulp that will

1. Take HTML files in each folder
2. Wrap the HTML files with some other HTML
3. Create a new file called `wrapped.html`
4. Put that file within that folder.

To wrap, I'd be using [gulp-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wrapper) And to attempt renaming the file, I used [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename)

### Expected Results:

Take **page1/page.html**:

```
<h1>This is page 1 content</h1>
```

In a folder structure like this:

```
page1/
    page.html
page2/
    page.html
```

Running the Gulp task would turn into

```
page1/
    page.html
    wrapped.html
page2/
    page.html
    wrapped.html
```

With **page1/wrapped.html** now looking like:

```
<header></header>
<h1>This is page 1 content</h1>
<footer></footer>
```

---

Currently, my code is

```
gulp.task('layout', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/page.html', { base: "./" })
    .pipe(wrapper({
       header: '<header></header',
       footer: '<footer></footer>'
    }))
    .pipe(rename("test.html"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

However, this will will just put the file in the `/` folder, not the one where it was sourced from.

And if I do:

```
gulp.task('layout', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/page.html', { base: "./" })
    .pipe(wrapper({
       header: '<header></header',
       footer: '<footer></footer>'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

This will put it in the folder it was sourced from, but just overwrite the existing file.

---

I'm not sure how to accomplish my acceptance criteria. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `basename` option for `gulp-rename`. From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename#notes):

> `basename` is the filename without the extension

This will work:

```
gulp.task('layout', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/**/page.html', { base: "./" })
   .pipe(wrapper({
     header: '<header></header>',
     footer: '<footer></footer>'
   }))
  .pipe(rename({basename: "test"}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```